# Android - get response status code using retrofit and coroutines

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have a retrofit Service:

```
suspend fun getArticles(): Articles
```

and usually I can get response code in `try/catch` in a case of error.

```
try {
    val articles = service.getArticles()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // I can get only codes different from 200...
}
```

But what if I need to distinguish between 200 and 202 codes for example and my service returns me only data object?

How to get response code if I have successful response?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your interface would look like this

```
suspend fun getArticles(): Response<Articles>
```

then you use like this

```
val response = service.getArticles()
response.code() //gives you response code
val articles = response.body
```

or easier solution is

```
if (response.isSuccessful){ // Successful is any code between the range [200..300)
    val articles = response.body
}
```

Comment: but if i not use Response<Articles> only Articles?

Comment: @Fortran you need to use `Response<Articles>` to be able to tell

Comment: Then you can use `response.code()` to get the actual HTTP response code.